# Angular md-switch .md-thumb color is not displaying correctly when toggling the switch

Tags: html, css, angularjs, safari, less

The md-switch when toggled on the Safari browser displays a yellow section on the md-thumb section of the switch.

[image]

The toggle should just be that blue color and have no yellow.  It turns yellow after toggling the switch on or off.  Other browser handle this toggle switch fine.  The `md-bar` is fine, but the `md-thumb' is what is yellow.  I tried setting everything to the blue I am using...

LESS

```
md-switch .md-thumb {
background-color: #29b6f6 !important;
color: #29b6f6 !important;
}

md-switch.md-checked .md-thumb {
background-color: #29b6f6 !important;
color: #29b6f6 !important;
}

md-switch[disabled] .md-thumb {
background-color: #29b6f6 !important;
color: #29b6f6 !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<md-switch ng-model="orgAdminSwitch" class="md-primary" ng-change="orgAdminChanged(orgAdminSwitch)" ng-show="isAdmin" aria-label="Org Admin Switch" style="float: right;"></md-switch>
```

But this only dimmed the yellow.  The yellow was still visible and this only happens in Safari when the switch is toggled on or clicked to toggle off.  Any idea on how to remove this?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this issue.  If you set `display: none` on the `md-switch .md-thumb: before` and `md-switch .md-ripple-container` it will stop the color glitch.  You will lose the ripple when toggling the switch but there will no longer be this combination of colors.  The issue itself is due to different colors coming through and combining to make this yellow color.  This is an issue only on the Safari browser, but this is an easy workaround and will solve the issue on all browsers.

The code will look like:

```
md-switch .md-thumb: before {
display: none;
}

md-switch .md-ripple-container {
display: none;
}
```